# rails select_tag with 2d options_for_select default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a `select_tag` with a 2d array for the `options_for_select` being a 2d array so that the displayed options are different from the stuff that is sent with the form (i.e. `options_for_select([["Option A", "this_get_submitted"],["Way Better Option", "this_is_the_other_option"]])`.

How do I set the default selection?

`select_tag(:choice, options_for_select(...), selected: "this_is_the_other_option"` doesn't work.

Comment: what if you do this `select_tag(:choice, options_for_select([["Option A", "this_get_submitted"],["Way Better Option", "this_is_the_other_option"]], "this_is_the_other_option" ))` will this work.?

Comment: yes it does. Make it an answer an I'll accept it.

Comment: Added the answer.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work, the second option in `options_for_select` is the one you want to show as default.

```
 select_tag(:choice, options_for_select([["Option A", "this_get_submitted"],["Way Better Option", "this_is_the_other_option"]], "this_is_the_other_option" ))
```